# Scheduled text on JSP

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, hyperlink, ognl

I am having a requirement to add a sentence on a JSP file with a hyperlink which it'll redirect to a different page and this sentence need to be automatically removed after two days from the deployment date.

**Example:**

```
<a href="http://www.example.com/football/schedule">Football tournament on 20th Jan 2014</a>
```

Is there any techniques available in Java to add a schedule job to a particular JSP text. I am using Struts2 in my application as well.

Comment: What about an If condition while showing link, Which checks the date.

Comment: if you are using database, then fetch the link related information with condition as `deployment_date = sysdate - 2` (_something like this_) and then use result in JSP. otherwise follow the comment from @zulox

Comment: @Swaraj: There's no databases. I'm having only the UI implementations.

Comment: Show the data structure used in your code.

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ: This is fine. Thanks Suresh, but when we put if condition then it'll execute once we reload the page only. But I need something which will automatically get executed, even without reloading the page on it's given schedule. It should be something like a scheduled task.

Comment: @zulox, do you want to remove the link permanently and don't want to replace it with new link? if this is not the case then use `static Date object` to store the deployment date and then check with current date every time your `JSP` page gets invoked and if difference btn current date & deployment date is 2 then show nothing.

Comment: @RomanC: Do you mean the code part? I have already shown how the link is appearing in above. It's a simple jsp page with some images and texts. And this link which I've mentioned above will be appearing and it should get obsoleted after two days from the deployment.

Comment: If the link gets obsoleted you can determine if you put a condition that will check that link is obsolete. You can do it in the JSP but preferable to do it in action where you could set a flag to make it obsolete.

Answer (score 0):

If condition for specified content

```
<s:if test="new java.util.Date().before(new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").parse("20/01/2014"))">
  <a href="http://www.example.com/football/schedule">Football tournament on 20th Jan 2014</a>
</s:if>
```